# Bad math operators space after \left. in aligned equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\redx}{{\color{red}x}}
\newcommand{\bluex}{{\color{blue}x}}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  x &= \biggl[ x \frac{\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{x}{y}} \notag \\
    & \quad \quad  + \redx \frac{\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{x}{y}}\biggr]
\end{align}

\begin{align}
  x &= \left[ x \frac{\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{x}{y}} \right.\notag \\
    & \quad \quad \left. + \bluex \frac{\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{x}{y}}\right]
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Look at the space between the `+` sign and the red x and the blue one.

My question is: how can I keep using the `\left` and `\right` macros across line breaks and fix (I hope not manually) the bad space arrangement between the math-operator and the following symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It seems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410679/bad-math-operators-space-after-left-in-aligned-equations/410700#comment1025215_410680) that I’d better explain what I meant in [my comment to Steven’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410679/bad-math-operators-space-after-left-in-aligned-equations/410680?noredirect=1#comment1025199_410680):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\redx}{{\color{red}x}}
\newcommand{\bluex}{{\color{blue}x}}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  x &= \biggl[ x \frac{\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{x}{y}} \notag \\
    & \quad \quad  + \redx \frac{\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{x}{y}}\biggr]
\end{align}

\begin{align}
  x &= \left[ x \frac{\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{x}{y}} \right.\notag \\
    & \quad \quad \! \left. \kern -\nulldelimiterspace
        {} + \bluex \frac{\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{x}{y}}\right]
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an empty group `{}` between the `\left.` and the `+`.   However, you cannot use `\left` and `\right` across line breaks.  The proper approach is the `\bigg` approach.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\redx}{{\color{red}x}}
\newcommand{\bluex}{{\color{blue}x}}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  x &= \biggl[ x \frac{\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{x}{y}} \notag \\
    & \quad \quad  + \redx \frac{\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{x}{y}}\biggr]
\end{align}

\begin{align}
  x &= \left[ x \frac{\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{x}{y}} \right.\notag \\
    & \quad \quad \left.{} + \bluex \frac{\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{x}{y}}\right]
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

If you want the *exact* spacing of the red one, you will also need to add some negative space, as the `\left.` does add extra horizontal space.  So, for example,

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\redx}{{\color{red}x}}
\newcommand{\bluex}{{\color{blue}x}}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  x &= \biggl[ x \frac{\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{x}{y}} \notag \\
    & \quad \quad  + \redx \frac{\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{x}{y}}\biggr]
\end{align}

\begin{align}
  x &= \left[ x \frac{\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{x}{y}} \right.\notag \\
    & \quad \quad \left.\!{} + \bluex \frac{\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{x}{y}}\right]
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

might be better.  In that case the result is

[image]

Comment: Do you know the exact amount of horizontal space added by `\left.`? (I tried `\mkern-\thickmuskip\left.{}` and it works fine).

Comment: Well, `$x\left.\mkern-5mu y\mkern-5mu\right.z$` and `$ x y z$` seem to match, so perhaps 5mu for `\mathord`.  However, I don't know if it is dependent on the whether the surrounding matter is `\mathord` or `\mathbin`, etc.  `$x\left.\mkern-5mu {}+{}\mkern-5mu\right.z$` and `$ x +z$` also work, if the `{}` are included.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi: compared to the `\biggl` case, `\left.` adds `\nulldelimiterspace` (normally .2pt), because you use a null delimiter, and `\thinmuskip` (normally 3.0mu) because a `\left ... \right` construction yields an Inner atom, and this Inner atom follows the Ord inserted by `&` (see the table on p. 170 of _The TeXbook_).  Note that `\nulldelimiterspace` is expressed in points, while `\thinmuskip` is in math units.  As you know, `\!` only compensate for the `\thinmuskip`.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi: Oops, there’s a typo in [my previous comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410679/bad-math-operators-space-after-left-in-aligned-equations/410680?noredirect=1#comment1025190_410680): the normal value of `\nulldelimiterspace` is not .2pt, but 1.2pt!  In any case, you don’t need to bother about this: just add `\kern -\nulldelimiterspace`!

Comment: @GuM `\kern -\nulldelimiterspace` doesn't works. I'm editing my question to show you the details.